# On vs In for Place

Tags: grammar

I recently read a really good article on https://www.clarkandmiller.com/

There is an explanation of On vs In for Place.

[image]

The author says that we cannot say "We spent all afternoon in the beach".

But as you can see in the picture, he says: "But if it feels like a 3-dimensional space, use in".

I know that it's weird to say "in the beach" but based on the rule of the picture, it would be ok.

My question is simple: Would it be correct to say: "We spent all afternoon in the beach"? even if the right way to say it is "at/on the beach.

P.S. Sorry if I don't ask the question on the referenced Website but there is no email to contact them. :)

Comment: No. I can't think of any context where you could say "in the beach". Even something _buried_ there would be described as being "**at** the beach, buried **in** the sand."

Comment: [*formed in the beach*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22formed+in+the+beach+%22&biw=919&bih=515&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLG0M5lxMTkHG3k7sA-mdXuf-0zoA%3A1634328024914&ei=2N1pYauKN8ulytMPj424mAg&oq=%22formed+in+the+beach+%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6664.9855.0.10086.8.8.0.0.0.0.225.920.3j4j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.110...33i299k1.0.y17SXgA7o8g)  does sometimes occur in geological/geographical writing, but not in everyday usage.

Comment: There are no consistent rules for this, some of them are just idiomatic.

Comment: What does 'spent all after' mean?

Comment: Sorry, I would say "afternoon" like in the image below.

Comment: @Samuel Do you feel a beach is a three-dimensional space that you're "in"?

Answer (score 3):

I think the author of the web page was trying to formulate a logical rule or pattern where, unfortunately, none exists. Some of the advice there seems mistaken to me, and some overgeneralizes from particular cases.

In many of these cases it is just a historical accident which preposition was more commonly used and became locked in as standard in a particular context.

Sometimes a logical rule can be devised. When we are referring to a surface we often say "on" so we day "The wood floats on the water" but "the swimmer was in the water for an hour."

We say that "He was at a play" but "I was in the theater". Perhaps the theater is more thought of as a container, while the play is an event. One is often "at" events.

"In the street" is much more common in  UK usage than in US usage, where it is very rarely heard, and particularly not for vehicles. I don't think it has much if anything to do with thinking of the street as 3D.